# Different behavior with FindAll for AutomationElement between MC++ and C#

Tags: c#, ui-automation, managed-c++, uia

I am trying to find the `ControlType.DataItem` children of a `DataGrid` control using UI automation in managed C++.  The following snippet works from C# on a known `HWND` value:

```cs
var automationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(new IntPtr(0x000602AE));
var propertyCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem);
var dataItems = automationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, propertyCondition).Count;
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} DataItem(s)", dataItems);
```

This yields the following output:

```
Found 2 DataItem(s)
```

Converting the code to MC++ yields zero results.  Here is the converted MC++ code:

```c
auto automationElement = AutomationElement::FromHandle(IntPtr(0x000602AE));
auto propertyCondition = gcnew PropertyCondition(AutomationElement::ControlTypeProperty, ControlType::DataItem);
auto dataItems = automationElement->FindAll(TreeScope::Subtree, propertyCondition)->Count;
Console::WriteLine("Found {0} DataItem(s)", dataItems);
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue using UI Automation from managed C++?  I've used MC++ for UIA in the past and this is the first difference that I have came across between using it from C#.  Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but it works whenever I extract the UI Automation code into another class and invoke it like that.  I do not claim to be an expert on MC++ or how it loads the .NET framework, but this is how I fixed my issue.

### Create the `AutomatedTable` Class

`AutomatedTable.h`

```c
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Automation;

ref class AutomatedTable {
public:
    AutomatedTable(const HWND windowHandle);

    property int RowCount {
        int get();
    }

private:
    AutomationElement^ _tableElement;
};
```

`AutomatedTable.cpp`

```c
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "AutomatedTable.h"

AutomatedTable::AutomatedTable(const HWND windowHandle) {
    _tableElement = AutomationElement::FromHandle(IntPtr(windowHandle));
}

int AutomatedTable::RowCount::get() {
    auto dataItemProperty = gcnew PropertyCondition(AutomationElement::ControlTypeProperty, ControlType::DataItem);
    return _tableElement->FindAll(TreeScope::Subtree, dataItemProperty)->Count;
}
```

### Invoke From `main.cpp`

`main.cpp`

```c
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AutomatedTable.h"

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
    auto automatedTable = gcnew AutomatedTable((HWND)0x000602AE);
    Console::WriteLine("Found {0} DataItem(s)", automatedTable->RowCount);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Found 2 DataItem(s)
```

Any insight as to why this is any different would be much appreciated :-)